# Minimagick Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, imagemagick, minimagick

Running on Ubuntu 16.04 with the following Setup: 
Ruby 2.2.4, Nginx + Passenger, ImageMagick 7.x

The problem: I am using Shrine and Minimagick. Everything works well in development, but once I release I get the following Error:

```
ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed
```

ImageMagick is installed correctly, and I can use it on the command line.

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-10 Q16 x86_64 2017-06-10 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib jbig jng jpeg lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

I tried to build ImageMagick manually, when installing via apt-get I first purged everything, and installed from scratch, etc. So I tried quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is related to the ENV['PATH'] variable. To solve this add the following line to your Nginx vhost:

*/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site*

```
passenger_env_var PATH <path-to-rails>/vendor/bundle/<ruby-version>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```